# Populate Excel sheet on incoming outlook 2016 email and modify email subject with added ticket number

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

What I'm trying to do is create a simple tracking/ticketing system with outlook and excel. I'm using Office 2016. Here's what I want to do:

When a new email is received, initiate a macro in excel that checks if it is a new email or reply/fwd. If it's new the excel sheet will create a new entry, and assign a ticket number. Now I want to append this ticket number to the email subject and send an automated reply to the sender.

I have some idea about excel vba, but I am struggling with the Outlook part. Any help or nudge in the right direction would be appreciated. I tried to extract some information from online tutorials but i feel a bit lost. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the piece of code that may help you to access the subject line of your mails from your outlook. Before applying the code do not forget to add reference of "Microsoft outlook 15.0 object library".

What you need to do is after accessing the subject line you can split it through "FW:" or "RE:" to check for forwarded mails or replied mails.

```
sub MailsImport()

Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim sFolders As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim iRow As Integer, oRow As Integer
Dim MailBoxName As String, Pst_Folder_Name  As String
Dim ProfileName As String

ProfileName = "Enter the outlook profile mail address" 'Ex: test.user@hotmail.com

'Mailbox or PST Main Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
MailBoxName = ProfileName

'Mailbox Folder or PST Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
Pst_Folder_Name = "Enter the folder name in your outlook profile" 'Example: "Inbox" or "Sent Items"

'To directly a Folder at a high level
'Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)

'To access a main folder or a subfolder (level-1)
For Each Folder In Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders
    If VBA.UCase(Folder.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then GoTo Label_Folder_Found
    For Each sFolders In Folder.Folders
        If VBA.UCase(sFolders.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then
            Set Folder = sFolders
            GoTo Label_Folder_Found
        End If
    Next sFolders
Next Folder

Label_Folder_Found:
 If Folder.Name = "" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
    GoTo End_Lbl1:
End If

'Read Through each Mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
Folder.Items.Sort "Received"

'Insert Column Headers
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2) = "Subject"
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3) = "Date"
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4) = "Size"
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 5) = "EmailID"
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Body"

'Export eMail Data from PST Folder to Excel with date and time
oRow = 1
For iRow = 1 To Folder.Items.Count
    'If condition to import mails received in last 60 days
    'To import all emails, comment or remove this IF condition
    If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime) <= 60 Then
       oRow = oRow + 1
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1).Select
       'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 2) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
       'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 3) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
       'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 4) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Size
       'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 5) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
       'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
    End If
Next iRow
Set Folder = Nothing
Set sFolders = Nothing
End_Lbl1:
End sub
```

For sending mails you can make use of powershell code which is very easy and simple:

```
$SmtpClient = new-object system.net.mail.smtpClient
$MailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage 
$SmtpServer = "your smtp servername" #Ex: mail1.hotmail.com
$SmtpClient.host = $SmtpServer 
$MailMessage.From = "Your mail id" #Ex: test.user@hotmail.com
$MailMessage.To.add("Mail id of the recipient") 
$MailMessage.Subject = "subject line for your mail"
$MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = 0

$MailMessage.Body = "//body of the mail
//body
//body
//body
//body"
$SmtpClient.Send($MailMessage)
```